# achieve vertical lines using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jsplumb

I am using [jsPlumb](http://www.jsplumb.org/) with success since a few months. I connect some div's with straight lines with no problems. Now I want to connect arbitrary div's placed anywhere with vertical or horizontal lines. To achieve this objective, I place lines using anchors testing each time the correct values of X,Y for each endpoint.

My objective is to place dynamically vertical or horizontal lines without having to recalculate statically the X,Y anchor values each time. Is there any possibility? Are there better alternatives to jsPlumb to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

jsPlumb has special 'flowchart' connectors that run in either horizontal or vertical directions.

Demo: http://www.jsplumb.org/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html

Docs: http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/content.html#connectors

Comment: this demo shows corners, I want pure vertical lines, straight.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding your question. Can you be a little more specific in what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: I want straight lines, from one point to another, without corners.  And these lines must be horizontal or vertical, not diagonal.